# Calendar: date_started until Date.current?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

How can we go from `date_started` until `Date.current`?

For example, this code only counts the `date_started` for a routine:

```
routines = current_user.routines.group_by {|i| i.date_started.to_date}
classes << "completed" if routines.include?(day)
```

But I'd like to make "completed", which is the CSS class that makes the td background blue, work like I explain below:

[image]

**schema**

```
create_table "routines", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "date_started"
  t.string   "action"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

I had followed this **[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndBKSjAbemo)** to build the calendar.

**FULL calendar_helper.rb**

```
module CalendarHelper
    def calendar(date = Date.current, &block)
        Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
    end

    class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
        HEADER = %w[Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat]
        START_DAY = :sunday

        delegate :content_tag, :current_user, to: :view

        def past
        end

        def table
            content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
                header + week_rows
            end
        end

        def header
            content_tag :tr do
                HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
            end
        end

        def week_rows
            weeks.map do |week|
                content_tag :tr do
                    week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
                end
            end.join.html_safe
        end

        def day_cell(day)
            content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
        end

        def day_classes(day)
            classes = []
            classes << "lastmonth" if day.month < date.month
            classes << "nextmonth" if day.month > date.month
            ###
            routines = current_user.routines.group_by {|i| i.date_started.to_date}
            classes << "completed" if routines.include?(day)
            ### 
            classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
        end

        def weeks
            first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
            last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
            (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly why not just check if the given day in the calender falls within your specified range of dates?

controller:

```
@date_started = Date.today - 2.days
@today = Date.today
@given_date = Date.yesterday
```

html:

```
<td class="<%= 'completed' if @given_date >= @date_started and @given_date <= @today %>">
```

EDIT

I suppose `@given_date` will need to be an array so each day can be iterated in your HTML. It's not clear how to write that without seeing how you're rendering your calender. But the general idea should work.

EDIT2

The tutorial HTML is something like this:

```
<%= calender do |date| %>
  <%= date.day %>
  # assuming this is where you add your `completed` css class somehow
  # check if date.day falls between the @date_started and @today range
<% end %>
```

EDIT3

Okay I see why this is confusing now. I think I understand though. You have have many `routine` objects and you want any date that falls between the `routine.date_started` and `Date.today` to be highlighted blue. I believe this will work for you:

```
def day_classes(day)
  classes = []
  classes << "lastmonth" if day.month < date.month
  classes << "nextmonth" if day.month > date.month
  ###
  routines = current_user.routines.group_by {|i| i.date_started.to_date}
  # remove this line:
  #classes << "completed" if routines.include?(day)
  # in favor of this line:
  classes << "completed" if routines.any? {|date_attr, routine_obj| day >= date_attr and day <= Date.today } 
  ### 
  classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I'm not sure if I understand why that would prevent you from doing what I'm saying. I will update based on your tutorial link.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Oops my logic was mistaken, I re-edited EDIT3 to fix it.

Comment: The idea is if `day` (the current day we are evaluating on the calender) is greater than **any** of the `route.date_started` and less than `Date.today` then add `"completed"`.